# Iteration skipping lines in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, enumerate

I'm trying to iterate through a whole dataframe which is already organized.
The idea is to find when a common user has an main_user aswell, when the keys that I use in the code below have a match these users have a main_user.

The problem I have is that some line are being skipped through the iteration and I can't find the error in the code.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
dataframe = gf.read_excel_base(path, sheet_name)
organized_dataframe = gf.organize_dataframe(dataframe)


main_user_data = {
    'Nome titular': '',
    'Nome beneficiário': '', 
    'Id Plano de Benefícios': '', 
    'Id Contratado': ''
    }

user_data = {
    'Nome titular': '',
    'Nome beneficiário': '', 
    'Id Plano de Benefícios': '', 
    'Id Contratado': ''
    }

main_user_list = []
user_list = []

for i, a in enumerate(organized_dataframe['Id Contratado']):
    if gf.is_main_user(organized_dataframe, i):
        main_user_data = gf.user_to_dict(organized_dataframe, i)
    else:
        user_data = gf.user_to_dict(organized_dataframe, i)
        print(user_data['Nome beneficiário'])
        if (main_user_data['Nome titular'] and main_user_data['Id Plano de Benefícios'] and main_user_data['Id Contratado']) == (user_data['Nome titular'] and user_data['Id Plano de Benefícios'] and user_data['Id Contratado']):
            print('deu match')
            main_user_list.append(main_user_data['Nome beneficiário'])
            user_list.append(user_data['Nome beneficiário'])

print(user_list)
```

The resulting list always stops somewhere in the middle of the dataframe, there's a lot of lines that will match the statements I've made in the code, but somehow the code does not go into them.

Comment: `if (a and b) == (c and d)` probably does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @fsimonjetz was not the case, i've changed the code to:

```
if (main_user_data['Nome titular'] == user_data['Nome titular'] and main_user_data['Id Plano de Benefícios'] == user_data['Id Plano de Benefícios'] and main_user_data['Id Contratado'] == user_data['Id Contratado']):```

and it keeps giving the same error.
actually it does not give any error, but the list continues incomplete

Comment: I've found the problem. It's in the gf.organize_dataframe()
Somehow it doesn't work properly. I'll try to get it right.